# Run all methods in a class C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with over 200 functions. I need to have a function to run all of the methods in the class.

All of the functions return `void`, and take no parameters.

This is what I currently have:

```
public void runAllFunctions()
{
        var methods = typeof(win10).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        object[] parameters = null;
        foreach (var method in methods)
        {
            if (method.Name.StartsWith("WN10"))
            {
                method.Invoke(null, parameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

With this code, I get the error "Non-static method requires a target"

How can I run all of the methods?

Comment: You need to pass the object instance as the first argument to `Invoke`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide `win10` class *instance*; if `runAllFunctions` is a method of `win10`:

```
  public void runAllFunctions() {
    var methods = GetType()
      .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Where(item => item.Name.StartsWith("WN10"));

    foreach (var method in methods)
      method.Invoke(this, new Object[0]); // please, notice "this"
  }
```

In case `runAllFunctions` is *not* a method of `win10`:

```
  public void runAllFunctions() {
    win10 instance = new win10(); //TODO: put right constructor here

    var methods = instance
      .GetType()
      .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
      .Where(item => item.Name.StartsWith("WN10"));

    foreach (var method in methods)
      method.Invoke(instance, new Object[0]);
  }
```

Comment: You may also want to add `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, otherwise it'll try to call both `ToString(T1)` and `Equals(T1, T2)` methods too,

Comment: BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Static

Comment: @David Q: better not use `BindingFlags.NonPublic` when method of interest is `public` one: we don't want to *interfere* with class's `private` affairs. `BindingFlags.Static` is of no use here: according to the error message "*Non-static method* requires a target" the method is definetely non-static. So `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` is enough

Answer (score 5):

First create an instance of type

```
win10 instance = new win10();
```

And then use it in your loop

```
method.Invoke(instance , parameters);
```